# Asset Library Not Showing Files And Giving Errors

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've uploaded the library and config and helper and have the library and helper to autoload with the autoload file. I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting this error message.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/index.php/auth/login

I have this inside the head tag of my default layout.

```
<?php echo css('reset.css'); ?>
<?php echo css('screen.css'); ?>
<?php echo css('fancybox.css'); ?>
<?php echo css('jquery.wysiwyg.css'); ?>
<?php echo css('jquery.ui.css'); ?>
<?php echo css('visualize.css'); ?>
<?php echo css('visualize-ligh.css'); ?>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<?php echo css('ie7.css'); ?>
<![endif]-->
```

Edit: Does anyone understand the errors though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my links to look like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/css/reset.css" type="text/css"/>
```

for each file.